# Publishing VS project to Github Pages

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017, github-pages

I have my project code on github here: https://github.com/mrdcs92/trip-planner

But when I try to reach the hosted project at https://mrdcs92.github.io/trip-planner/ , all I see is the readme file.  Are there files that need to be in a different directory for the project to run on github pages?  This is my first large project that I have done, so I'm not sure how to host this project correctly compared to my other existing projects that consist of just an index.html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub pages can only host static content (as you said - "just an Index.html page").

What you have is a .NET Website. GitHub does not host these. You will need a Hosting provider who can host .NET Core 1.1 Websites.

I know Azure can do this, and has some level of [free hosting](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/?v=17.39a), but you will have to google around for a hosting provider that meets your needs.

Usually you have a "Publish" setup from your Project to the Hosting Provider, if you are using a Build system, like VSTS, App Veyor, etc. you would have that publish the site, if not, you can use the option in Visual Studio.